# SVG Images not visible when ie9 with ie8 standards is used

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

when ie9 with ie8 standards is used, svg images is not visible in my website.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: There's no option other than not to use ie8 standards if you want to see svg images.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an image fallback to deal with browsers that don't support SVG:

```
<img src="images/YourImage.svg" onerror="this.src='images/YourImage.png'"/>
```

If the browser doesn't support SVG, it will fail to load the image (since it will not accept the SVG MIME type), and will throw an error that will be captured by `onerror`, which will replace it using JavaScript.